# AJAX - Post Table Rows and Individual Inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a project in Laravel that I am working on and one portion requires me to work with submitting a form through a modal, the problem is I'm not as familiar with AJAX as I'd like to be and I've run into an issue.

Here are the modal contents:

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <select name="payer_id" class="js-basic-single payer_id" style="width:100%;" id="payer_id">
                 <option></option>
                 @foreach($customers as $customer)
                 <option value="{{ $customer->id }}">{{ $customer->customer_name }}</option>
                 @endforeach
            </select>
            <div id="existing_biller_details" class="hidden" name="existing_biller_details" style="margin-top:10px;">
                </div>
            <select class="form-control deposit_type" name="deposit_type" id="deposit_type">
            <option disabled selected>Please Select</option>
            <option value="Check">Check</option>
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                <option value="ECheck">ECheck</option>
            </select>
            <div name="check_number" id="check_number" class="hidden">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Check Number" class="form-control" id="check_number" name="check_number">
              </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Payment Amount" name="payment_amount" id="payment_amount">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Deposit" name="date_deposit" id="date_deposit">
            <textarea placeholder="Notes" style="width:100%;" class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes"></textarea>
        </td><td style="width:50%;">
            <table style="width:100%;" id="freight_bill_items">
                <thead>

                    <td style="width:30%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Bill No.</td><td style="width:30%; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Amount</td>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="height:40px">
                <td style="width:30%;text-align:center;"><input type="text" name="payment_details[shipment_id][]" required class="form-control name_list" id="shipment_id" placeholder="Bill No." required></td><td style="width:30%;text-align:center;"><input type="text" name="payment_details[amount][]" required class="form-control name_list" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" required>
                        </td><td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
                <div id="freight_bill_items_subtotal;" style="font-weight:bold; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:left; background-color: #f0f8ff;">
                SUBTOTAL:
                    <input type="text" readonly name="freightBillSubtotal" id="freightBillSubtotal" class="form-control total_field" style="display:inline;" value="0.00">
                </div>




            </td>    
        </tr>
        </table>
```

As you can see a little bit lower, there is a div called "freight_bill_items", with a table and in the only tbody row, the two text inputs and a button to add another table row with the same exact inputs.

Now here at the moment is my ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.createPayment', function() {
            $('.modal-title').text('Record New Payment');
            $('#payment').modal('show');
        });
        $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.add_payment', function() {
            //START
            var payment_details = [];
            //END
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/payments/createNew',
            data: {
                payer_id: $('input[name=payer_id]').val(),
                notes: $('input[name=notes]').val(),
                payment_amount: $('input[name=payment_amount]').val(),
                date_deposit: $('input[name=date_deposit]').val(),
                check_number: $('input[name=check_number]').val(),
                deposit_type: $('input[name=deposit_type]').val(),
                payment_details:payment_details, //LOOKING FOR ASSISTANCE HERE//
                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#payment').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Validation error - Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Successfully recorded Payment!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});

                    }
                },
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now what I'm stuck on is how do I pass these rows and their input contents into arrays to POST along with the other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you remove **id** from inputs that are duplicated. Assign a class instead.The shipment id can be assigned as an attribute.

```html
<input class="payment_details" shipment_id="{shipment_id}" value="" required>
```

```
function get_array(element){
    // Inputs having mutliple fields(grouped by class) will be returned as an array
    arr = [];
    element.map(function(){
        arr[$(this).attr('shipment_id')] = $(this).val();
    });
    return arr;
}

var payments = get_array($('.payment_details'));
```

You now have an array whose key is shipment_id and value is input value for the respective element. Pass this array in your AJAX.